# Excel data to Python via web service, data structure for variable data

Tags: python, vba, excel, data-structures

I have an excel spreadsheet which basically acts as an UI, it is used to let the user enter some parameters which are then passed to some python code on a server via a web service, as well as a whole tab full of data.

I am by far no VBA expert but managed to get my data and individual variables submitted. My question is what is the best suited VBA data structure to use, ideally I would like to have something like a dictionary where the keys would be my defined Names for the Excel cells, plus the data which might for some cases will be a single value or a Variant array.

I have to be able to distinguish between keys and their corresponding values in python eventually.

So far I was playing around with collections

```
Dim Main_tab_vars As Collection
Set Main_tab_vars = New Collection
Main_tab_vars.Add Range("Start_Date").Value, "Start_Date_var", "Start_Date_var" 
Main_tab_vars.Add Range("Definitions").Value, "Definitions_var"
```

If I look at the collection in my watches window I can see the values correctly stored in item1 and item2. But it looks like my key information gets lost

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend either JSON or Xml when sending data to a web service, these are the industry standards.  If chooisng JSON then you'd use nested dictionaries and then build a string (plenty of code on internet) when ready .  If using Xml then you could build up the Xml document as you go.

I do not know how well Python handles JSON so probably I'd opt for XML.

Comment: That's a good idea, python will have no problem reading in either into a data frame or dictionary